# Vertical CSS Menu with large top and left gaps

Tags: css

I have a vertical CSS menu but there is a gap to the left and above and i cannot work out where to remove it - my menu CSS is below and i have created a fiddle with my full code:

```
#vertical_menu {
    float:left;
}
#vertical_menu > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:140px;
}
#vertical_menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:-20px;
}
#vertical_menu li a {
    display:block; 
    padding-bottom:10px;
    margin-top:15px;
    border-bottom:4px solid #000000;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#vertical_menu li a:hover { 
    border-color:#666666; 
    color:#666666
}
```

any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/Dfw9f/1/

Comment: plz post on what browser you got this? note that you need to reset the margin for ul

Comment: on google chrome for Mac

Comment: You should use a reset CSS

Comment: please pick a correct answer so that people who see this in the future will know what worked, and what didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding this to your code will solve your problem:

```
ul
 {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
 }
```

Hope this helped.

**UPDATE**

I think the gap is not because of an issue with margin or padding, but because of an empty row in your table. You can see this by giving the table a border, like `<table border="1">` ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dfw9f/2/)).

I see that you included the last row of the table to have a line between the table and the menu. You can accomplish this simply by deleting the last row of the table (which is messing your layout) and add a `border-bottom` to the table, like `<table border="0" style="border-bottom:1px solid gray;">`

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dfw9f/3/) - here is an updated version, with the line and correctly laid out menu.

Hope this helped.

Comment: this helped the left gap but not the top one

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are looking for is a reset CSS, kindly check [CSS Tools: Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

> The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in
>   things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings

for quick solution just add this to your CSS

```
ul,tr,hr{margin:0;padding:0;}
```